# Most efficient way to upsample an image using ImageMagick?

Tags: image, imagemagick, resampling

I have a large set of images that vary in size and resolution and I'm using ImageMagick to upsample those of low resolution. Until now, I've been using the `-resample option` with `-sharpen` as follows: `convert [input image] -resample 500 -sharpen 0x2 [output image]`

The issue is that it seems rather slow. The `-sample` option is much faster, but the quality suffers. I'm also considering switching to GraphicsMagick for a boost in performance. What is the most efficient way to upsample these images?

Some context: I am upsampling these low resolution images to increase the accuracy of an OCR tool for text recognition. The poor quality of the image causes wildly inaccurate OCR results.

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't get any drastic speed improvements, but here are some things you can try:

- Try different [resampling filters](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/#filter).
- Try different (smaller) [support window sizes](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/#support).
- Remove the extra sharpening step and use the [filter:blur setting](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/#blur) instead.